# insert data from foreach PHP containing an array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I am using the codeigniter framework, and I am running to a bit of a problem trying to save data from a form.

How do I insert a new row for each user_answer containing the other information?

Thanks!

This is my foreach loop in the controller and the call to the model

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)  
        {  
            $data[$key] = $this->input->post($key);  
        } 
$this->quiz_model->save_answers($data);
```

This is the model

```
function save_answers($data)
    {
            foreach ($data['user_answer'] as $key) {
                    $this->db->insert('answer', $data);
            }       
    }
```

Table is setup as

- answer_id (auto increment)
- quiz_id
- question_id
- user_id
- user_answer

Var dumps

```
data => array(3) { ["user_id"]=> string(9) "anonymous" ["quiz_id"]=> string(2) "24" ["question_id"]=> string(2) "18" ["user_answer"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" } }

data['user_answers'] => array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }
```

error

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `answer` (`user_id`, `quiz_id`, `question_id`, `user_answer`) VALUES ('anonymous', '24', Array)
```

Comment: First I would use prepared statements, something codeigniter doesn't have. I would recommend you use mysqli in your model. You are vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: @Robert Rocha as long as he is using db->insert his "All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries." Also, you can use PDO and mysqli queries. Per the codeigniter docuentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create new set of data per user_answer. Try this:

```
function save_answers($data)
{
        foreach ($data['user_answer'] as $key) {
                $new_data = array('user_id' => $data['user_id'], 'quiz_id' => $data['quiz_id'], 'question_id' => $data['question_id'], 'user_answer' => $key)
                $this->db->insert('answer', $new_data);
        }       
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what the doctor ordered!

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in `foreach` loop. Change your `save_answers` method to :

```
function save_answers($data)
{
        foreach ($data['user_answer'] as $key=>$value) { //<------------change here
                $data_insert = array('user_id'=>$data['user_id'],'quiz_id'=>$date['quiz_id'],'question_id'=>$data['question_id'],'user_answer'=>$value); //create new array
                $this->db->insert('answer', $data_insert);//<------------change here
        }       
}
```